# Particle coordinates?

Tags: particles

Lets say I have a some particles flying out into space from an emitter, can I get access to their coordinates?

I know the coordinates of the emitter, but the particles themselves, surely they are stored somewhere.

I would like to eventually have a constraint pointing at a particle.
A bone stretching to a particle as it moves would be nice, or a damped track, or a copy location constraint.

Comment: You can get them through python, is this your question?

Comment: Would be better if I could get it through buttons, but if thats what it takes, im willing to use drivers.

Comment: Do you know their location in python? DNA address its called, I think.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't think using drivers with particles or viewing them in the UI is a good idea.

Comment: Use particles as hooks for a lattice

Comment: I know I can convert the particles to mesh and then get access to their coordinates, but the downside is I wont be able to make any edits in real time

Comment: Consider using Animation Nodes for that, getting the particles locations can be done using only two [nodes](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/particles/particles_data.html).

Comment: Woah, very nice, didnt know this existed. Thank You, will post a legit answer once I figure it out unless you want to do the honors.

Comment: I can post an answer, but you are going to have to edit the question to give more details on what you want to achieve.